# Invalid character "\u64e" in token Pylance

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the meaning of this error `Invalid character "\u64e" in token Pylance` the read error line under `Acc` for this code, How can fixed it?

```
err = calculateCError()
print('Error is:', err, '%')
َAcc = 100 - err
print('َAccuracy is:',َAcc , '%')
```

Comment: \u64E appears to be the character "ARABIC FATHA". Did you use it instead of the minus sign somehow?

Comment: My guess is that one of the quotation marks has somehow been typed as an Arabic character. Perhaps the quotation mark at the beginning of the “accuracy is” print function; it looks different from the others.

Comment: Your letter A has a fatha over it in Acc and Accuracy

Comment: Please consider adding an upvote if my answer was useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to debug something like this:

```
s = """err = calculateCError()
print('Error is:', err, '%')
َAcc = 100 - err
print('َAccuracy is:',َAcc , '%')"""

print([hex(ord(c)) for c in s])
```

```
['0x65', '0x72', '0x72', '0x20', '0x3d', '0x20', '0x63', '0x61', '0x6c',
'0x63', '0x75', '0x6c', '0x61', '0x74', '0x65', '0x43', '0x45', '0x72',
'0x72', '0x6f', '0x72', '0x28', '0x29', '0xa', '0x70', '0x72', '0x69',
'0x6e', '0x74', '0x28', '0x27', '0x45', '0x72', '0x72', '0x6f', '0x72',
'0x20', '0x69', '0x73', '0x3a', '0x27', '0x2c', '0x20', '0x65', '0x72',
'0x72', '0x2c', '0x20', '0x27', '0x25', '0x27', '0x29', '0xa', '0x64e',
'0x41', '0x63', '0x63', '0x20', '0x3d', '0x20', '0x31', '0x30', '0x30',
'0x20', '0x2d', '0x20', '0x65', '0x72', '0x72', '0xa', '0x70', '0x72',
'0x69', '0x6e', '0x74', '0x28', '0x27', '0x64e', '0x41', '0x63', '0x63',
'0x75', '0x72', '0x61', '0x63', '0x79', '0x20', '0x69', '0x73', '0x3a',
'0x27', '0x2c', '0x64e', '0x41', '0x63', '0x63', '0x20', '0x2c', '0x20',
'0x27', '0x25', '0x27', '0x29']
```

And sure enough, there are three instances of 0x64E, always appearing before 0x41 (A). In fact, if you look carefully at your `A` characters, you will notice a faint slanted accent line above the `A`. This is called Arabic Fatha in Unicode. Here is a 320% zoom from my browser showing it more obviously:

[image]